# Add values from dictionary in csv file with specific keys under specific headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am creating a CSV file named myFile.csv which contains some fixed headers. I am getting a result from database using SQL query, so it has no fixed number of keys and values. I want to add the values from the dictionary result under specific headers.

I am getting list of dictionaries as result. I have tried the following code but I am not able to do it.

```
import csv

header = ['subject', 'salesorder id', 'invoice date', 'account id']
result = [{'subject': 'SR Release 2 Intranet', 'salesorder_id': '', 'customerno': '', 'contact_id': '4x4395', 'invoicedate': '2009-04-27', 'duedate': '2009-05-15'}, {'subject': 'Rechnung::ZChL::TP01::Relaunch::1.Rate', 'salesorder_id': '', 'customerno': '', 'contact_id': '4x8151', 'invoicedate': '2009-07-09', 'duedate': '2009-07-09'}]
values = []
for element in result:
    values.append(element['subject'])
    values.append(element['salesorder_id']) 
    values.append(element['invoicedate']) 
    values.append(element['account_id']) 
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    
    writer.writerow(values)
```

Following is the intended output:
[image]

I want to put condition on the result keys for example that if it matches invoice_date then insert its value under invoice date header and so on.

Comment: How exactly do you get `result`? Dictionaries can't have each key more than once.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I have changed the code which I have also tried as I am in reality getting list of dictionaries

Comment: @mkrieger1 That is the point that there are many names in invoice which I dont want to include in the csv. Just some of the values. There can also be some values of some headers which cannot come from result. Nevertheless, I result and header should be independent but code should insert some values from the result into the csv under specific headers.

Comment: Like under subject should be subject and under invoice date should be invoicedate but if I add header named "misc" it should only create a header with empty values until unless some values from result is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

From [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv), use `csv.DictWriter()` and make things simpler:

```
import csv

result = [{'subject': 'SR Release 2 Intranet', 'salesorder_id': '', 'customerno': '', 'contact_id': '4x4395', 'invoicedate': '2009-04-27', 'duedate': '2009-05-15'}, {'subject': 'Rechnung::ZChL::TP01::Relaunch::1.Rate', 'salesorder_id': '', 'customerno': '', 'contact_id': '4x8151', 'invoicedate': '2009-07-09', 'duedate': '2009-07-09'}]
with open('subject_test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    headers = result[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)

cat subject_test.csv
subject,salesorder_id,customerno,contact_id,invoicedate,duedate
SR Release 2 Intranet,,,4x4395,2009-04-27,2009-05-15
Rechnung::ZChL::TP01::Relaunch::1.Rate,,,4x8151,2009-07-09,2009-07-09
```

Comment: Header should be different from result as there are many keys in result which should not be inserted as header in csv. And there can be some headers whose value is not coming from result .In this code result's keys are the headers but headers and result should be independent.

Comment: That is a pretty loose description that depends on information not present in your question. If you want a answer you will need to add to your question a detailed  description of what you are trying to achieve with sample input and sample output. In other words a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: I have added the expected output with some description of what is it I need. @Adrian Klaver

Comment: 1) Per [Don't upload Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), do not use image for textual data. Copy and paste as text. 2) This does not come close to a MRE Minimal, Reproducible Example. You have not provided input data, a mapping of data headers to desired output headers or example of adding new field to output.